# How to VLOOKUP with various conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables. I'd like to find a D column value from table2 that corresponds to a condition: column C of table2 is equal to column "C&D" from table1 and column I of table2 is "ok".

Table1

[image]

Table 2
[image]

I was thinking something about this formula:

```
=IF(AND(F3="si";KIT!I3="ok");VLOOKUP(C3&D3;KIT!C:D;2;0);)
```

but unfortunately it does not work and takes just the first lookup value.

Comment: Where's the formula going? (What cells do you want it in) - Table 2, column D?

Comment: actually table1 column J, column D of the table2 must be a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=IF(F3="si";LOOKUP(2;1/(KIT!C:C=C3&D3)/(KIT!I:I="OK");KIT!D:D);0)
```

It would be better if you could restrict the number of rows rather than using entire column references.

To explain:
`(KIT!C:C=C3&D3)` will return an array of True or False values. Excel will calculate those as 1 and 0 respectively.
Dividing 1 by that array will return an array containing 1 or #DIV/0 (1 where the condition is met, #DIV/0 otherwise.
Dividing that result by the `(KIT!I:I="OK")` array has a similar effect and the resulting array only contains 1 where all conditions have been met, or #DIV/0 otherwise.

Searching for 2 in this array will find the last value less than or equal to 2 in that array. Since LOOKUP ignores errors, that will be the last occurrence of 1 (the only occurrence, if only one row matches the conditions)

Finally the corresponding value from column D is returned as the result.

Hopefully that makes some sense!

Comment: I need to test it for more values, but just doing a fast check seems it works correctly. Could you please also explain what is 2;1 in the formula? Thanks.

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer.